# Angularjs share functions inside service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-scenario

I am working with an angular app, where service are as declared as follows:

```js
App.service("myService", function(){
  this.calculation1 = function(){
    var util = function(){
    }
    //doing somthing
  }
  this.calculation2 = function(){

    // how can I call util function here?
  }
}
```

I want to use util function inside calculation2 method.

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define `util` as a closure variable so that it is a closure variable for both `calculation1` and `calculation2` methods

Comment: `self = this` then inside calculation2 `self.calculation1().util()`

Answer (score 3):

Just declare it outside the `calculation1` function:

```js
App.service("myService", function(){
  var util = function(){
  }
  this.calculation1 = function(){
    //doing something
  }
  this.calculation2 = function(){

  }
}
```